# weird letters and signs when reading csv file

Tags: sqlite, csv, csvreader

I am trying to open csv table and use it with sqlite. I've tried several methods but they all result with a table which inserts \n instead of a blank space ' ' or Â letters.
I tried to change the encoding but everything i do seems to end up with the same format. Please help!
This is my code:

```
import csv_to_sqlite

options=csv_to_sqlite.CsvOptions(typing_style='full', encoding='windows-1250')
input_file = ["./datasets/choco_flavors/flavors_of_cacao.csv"] 
csv_to_sqlite.write_csv(input_file, "flavors_of_cacao.sqlite", options)
con=sqlite3.connect("flavors_of_cacao.sqlite")
filter_data=pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM flavors_of_cacao""",con)
```

and the result of the first column title is "CompanyÂ \n(Maker-if known)"

Thank you

Comment: This is amost certainly an encoding issue, maybe your source is stored in UTF-8 ? If I store a UTF-8 text `Å Æ Ø`  and read as Windows 1251 (Western europe), the text reads  `Ã… Ã† Ã˜` (so characters similar to what you see). If you are "lucky" the Win1250 encoding of the bytes contain Â plus linefeed.   Could you paste example of original source file ?

Comment: This is the first row of the csv file:             
 "Company 
(Maker-if known)","Specific Bean Origin
or Bar Name",REF,"Review
Date","Cocoa
Percent","Company
Location",Rating,"Bean
Type","Broad Bean
Origin"